# Nullable reference type information not exposed from FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core-3.0, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I wanted to test out the new [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) feature in C# 8.0.

I started a new project targeting .NET Core 3.0, enabled nullable reference types in the `.csproj` file, and started coding. I created a simple list that takes a `string[]` and returns the `string` in that array that equals `abc`. Now, because I am not certain that `abc` actually exists in the array, I use `FirstOrDefault()`, which should default to `null` if a match is not found.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

public string FindArgument(string[] args)
{
    var arg = args.FirstOrDefault(x => x == "abc");
    return arg;
}
```

My method returns `string`, which *should* now be the *non-nullable* type. Since `FirstOrDefault()` may return `null`, I would expect the above method to yield a warning when returning the *maybe null* `arg` variable. It does not.

Looking at the the signature for `FirstOrDefault()` in Visual Studio, **it is clear why**: The method returns a `string`, not the nullable equivalent `string?` I would expect.

Using the method body below does yield the warning I expected:

```cs
var arg = args.Contains("abc") ? "abc" : null;
return arg;
```

Do system libraries (in this example `System.Linq`) really not expose nullability information when targeting .NET Core 3.0?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like `System.Linq` is not nullable annotated in the 3.0 release. So Nullable Reference Types does not emit the correct warning.

You can check similar problems in the [roslyn repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22New+Language+Feature+-+Nullable+Reference+Types%22). [This open issue on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/38941) is very similar to your problem. In that issue a contributor explains the current problem:

> `System.Linq` is nullable annotated in **master** branch of corefx, but not in **release/3.0**. So there's nothing unexpected in compiler.
>   The compiler should provide some diagnostics showing that you are using nullable-oblivious stuff.

Comment: To add to this, you can use [this package](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/ReferenceAssemblyAnnotator) to get the right annotations today.

Comment: This is still the case in .NET Core 3.1. It makes working with nullable reference types less nice. I believe the pull request [corefx/pull/40651](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/40651) fixes this, but apparently we will have to wait until **.NET 5** to get that :-(

Comment: Dirty work around.... Select your item, casted to nullable type. Re-shaper complains its redundant, but does work. 

var nullableMatch = collection.Select(x => (MyType?) x).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field == value);