# Is this the limitation of C# nullable checking?

Tags: c#, nullable

I've had the following CS8629 warning on my reference to `x`. Because of the `where` clause before the `select`, I am sure that `x.Value` will never be a nullable reference. Is this the intrinsic limitation of the C# null checking? Is there any way to get rid of the CS8629 warning other than suppressing it?

```
var myEnums = myStrings
      .Select(x => x.ToEnum<MyEnum>())
      .Where(x => x.HasValue)
      .Select(x => x.Value)  //CS8629 on x.
      .ToList();
```

```
MyEnum? ToEnum(this string str);
```

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/33539 Your best bet is likely to write your own `WhereNotNull` extension method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the limit. LINQ is not annotated with nullable annotations, yet. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58671188/5133585), [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/37468) and [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/38941), which are all open.

If you really don't want to use `!`, you can write something like:

```
static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(this Nullable<T> t) where T : struct {
    if (t.HasValue) {
        return Enumerable.Repeat(t.Value, 1);
    }
    return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}
```

Then use `SelectMany`:

```
var myEnums = myStrings
      .Select(x => x.ToEnum())
      .SelectMany(x => x.AsEnumerable())
      .ToList();
```

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov This is inspired by Java's `Optional.stream` method, used in conjunction with `flatMap` :) There is also `maybeToList` in Haskell. It's not really _that_ uncommon.

Comment: Creating a new state machine for each element is a bit costly. Why not filter and select in one go `WhereHasValue<T>(this IEnumerable<Nullable<T>> t)) ...`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yeah, I suppose that's true. I just wanted this to be as concise as possible. (I'm lazy :D) How about using `Enumerable.Repeat` and `Enumerable.Empty`?

Answer (score 0):

While there will be no null return, Try cast the `MyEnum?` to `MyEnum`.

Like this:

```
MyEnum myEnums = myStrings
      .Select(x => x.ToEnum<MyEnum>())
      .Where(x => x.HasValue)
      .Select(x => x.Value)  //CS8629 on x.
      .ToList();
```